# Toggling menu and click counter reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started to learn some JS and jQuery, and i'm trying to achieve a toggling menu that resets the clicks counter on the other menu when it is being opened.

[And here is the JS code](http://jsfiddle.net/jb66H/1/)

```
// JavaScript Document
      var toggleclicks = $('.toggle').data('clicks'); 
      var menuclicks = $('.toggle-menu').data('clicks');    
$(document).ready(function() {


//WRAPPER//
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
      ++toggleclicks;
      if (toggleclicks%2 === 0) {
         // even clicks
         $('.wrapper').css({'margin-top': '-260px'});
         $('.icon-menu, .icon-bell').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
         $('.toggle-menu').data('clicks',0)
      } else {
         // odd clicks
         $('.wrapper').css({'margin-top': '0'});
         $('.icon-bell').css({'color': 'red'});
         $('.contact, .diet, .hours, .classes, .gym').css({'margin-bottom': '-300px'});
         $('.main-nav').css({'width': '0'});
         $('.icon-menu').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
      }
    });

//NAV BAR//
    $('.toggle-menu').click(function() {
      ++menuclicks;  
      if (menuclicks%2 === 0) {
         // even clicks
         $('.main-nav').css({'width': '0'});
         $('.icon-menu, .icon-bell').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
         $('.toggle').data('clicks',0)
      } else {
         // odd clicks
         $('.main-nav').css({'width': '50%'});
         $('.icon-menu').css({'color': 'red'});
         $('.icon-bell').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
         $('.wrapper').css({'margin-top': '-260px'});
         $('.contact, .diet, .hours, .classes, .gym').css({'margin-bottom': '-300px'});
      }
    });
```

** [As you can see, the toggle won't work](http://boazkerengil.com). any suggestions?**

Thanks!

Comment: `if (toggleclicks%2 === '0')` will be `if (toggleclicks%2 === 0)` You will always get number as a reminder not a string!

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting an error message in the browser console? Any unexpected behavior? Including the relevant HTML code and/or setting up a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) would help.

Comment: Are you sure `$('.toggle')` and `$('.toggle-menu')` are available in the DOM at the beginning? Could be that jQuery does a noop returning null for clicks because the statements are outside the ready function and executed during interpretation and not on DOMReady.

Comment: I've edited the code above so it will work, but now i can't reset menuclicks, because it is no longer a global variable. the website is: http://boazkerengil.com as you can see, the .toggle is the bell icon, and the .menuclicks counter is related to the menu icon. As you can see in the website, i'm trying to reset the counters because  when you open a menu without closing the other, it ruins the odd/even count.

Comment: Ahh the question as been edited before i could answer based on the previous one ;) again checking it now @user3608136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, iv'e managed to solve the problem!

I got rid of the 'clicks' counter, and replaced it with numeric counter, with global variables and a reset line at the end of each else statement.

```
// JavaScript Document
var toggleclicks = 0;
var menuclicks = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
//WRAPPER//
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
      ++toggleclicks;
      if (toggleclicks%2 === 0) {
         // even clicks
         $('.wrapper').css({'margin-top': '-260px'});
         $('.icon-menu, .icon-bell').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
      } else {
         // odd clicks
         $('.wrapper').css({'margin-top': '0'});
         $('.icon-bell').css({'color': 'red'});
         $('.contact, .diet, .hours, .classes, .gym').css({'margin-bottom': '-300px'});
         $('.main-nav').css({'width': '0'});
         $('.icon-menu').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
         menuclicks = 0;
      }
    });

//NAV BAR//
    $('.toggle-menu').click(function() {
      ++menuclicks;  
      if (menuclicks%2 === 0) {
         // even clicks
         $('.main-nav').css({'width': '0'});
         $('.icon-menu, .icon-bell').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
      } else {
         // odd clicks
         $('.main-nav').css({'width': '50%'});
         $('.icon-menu').css({'color': 'red'});
         $('.icon-bell').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
         $('.wrapper').css({'margin-top': '-260px'});
         $('.contact, .diet, .hours, .classes, .gym').css({'margin-bottom': '-300px'});
         toggleclicks = 0;
      }
    });
```

You can check it on http://boazkerengil.com

Thanks everyone for your help, it's been really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image: enter code here]

As you can see from the image,  when you use === , the type of the condition matters.

`===` matches the exact type of both the values.

so in your case,  you are storing numeric in data-clicks but trying to access `'0'` which is a  string. So it's not matching.

Instead you can just use `==` which will match both

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! i changed a bit the code, using another method for the if statement. any idea how can do it with global variables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but it toggles correctly and you case use the .data as globals. Maybe if you post more of your code I could give you the working solution.

```
var toggleclicks = $('.toggle').data('clicks'); 
var menuclicks = $('.toggle-menu').data('clicks');  
$(document).ready(function() {
//WRAPPER//

 $('.toggle').click(function() {
    ++toggleclicks;
  if (toggleclicks%2 === 0) {
     // even clicks //
     $('.wrapper').css({'margin-top': '-260px'});
     $('.icon-menu, .icon-bell').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
     $('.toggle-menu').data('clicks',0) //THIS IS THE OThER MENU
  } else {
     // odd clicks
     $('.wrapper').css({'margin-top': '0'});
     $('.icon-bell').css({'color': 'red'});
     $('.main-nav').css({'width': '0'});
     $('.icon-menu').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
  }
  //$('.toggle').data("clicks", !toggleclicks);
 });
});
```

Comment: I've used your advice and my code looks like this now: http://jsfiddle.net/jb66H/1/ and now it's not toggling.. check http://boazkerengil.com